# Total Invoices - Receipts not adding up

Tags: php, laravel

I have the next issue - I have a table `invoices` and a table with `receipts`. An invoice is created by an agent and I want to get the sold for each agent but the numbers are wrong.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$agents = Agent::get();
$invoices_receipts_agent = array();
foreach ($agents as $agent) {
     $payment_invoice = 0;
     $payment_recepit = 0;
     $id_agent = $agent->id_agent;

     $invoices = Invoice::whereAgent_id($id_agent)->get();
     foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {

         $payment_invoice = $payment_invoice + $invoice->total_pay;
         $recepits = Recepit::whereInvoice_id($invoice->id_invoice)->get();
         if (count($recepits) > 0) {
             foreach ($recepits as $recepit) {
                 $payment_recepit = $payment_recepit + $recepit->amount_payd;
             }
         }
    }

    $total = $payment_invoice - $payment_recepit;
    $total_agents = ['name' => $agent->name, 'total' => $total];
    array_push($invoices_receipts_agent, $total_agents);
}
```

I made a test and created two invoices for the agent with ID 5

```
First invoice: 10
Second invoice : 20
Total invoices: 30
```

Then I did a recepit for the second invoice and found the expected total:

```
Total: 10 + 20 - 20 = 10 (correct total)
```

And that's great, but I have an agent with 3600 invoices and something is wrong the total. The total (total = invoices - recepits) is too big, but I can't figure out why.

Extra detail: the fields for the numbers are `float`.

Comment: Can there be multiple receipts for a single invoice?

Comment: @AaronDietz yes can be multiple receipts

Comment: Specifically what output do you require, because the majority of this logic can be handled by the database, rather than PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an easier way to handle this issue using [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).
In this case, can define One-to-Many relationship between Agent and Invoice as:

```
class Agent {
  ...
  function invoices(){
   return $this->hasMany('App-Namespace\Invoice')
  }
}
```

...and define the inverse relationship on Invoice.
Then, you must do same between Invoice and Receipt models, since an Invoice can have one to many receipts.
So, if Agents table primary key is id you could say:

```
$agent = Agent::find($agent_id)->invoices->get();
```

...to get an agent invoices; or:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find($invoice_id)->receipts->get();
```

...to get all receipts for a specific invoice.

And finally implement your code:

```
  $agents =  Agent::all();
  $invoices_receipts_agent = array();

  foreach ($agents as $agent) {

    $payment_invoice = 0;
    $invoices = $agent->invoices->get();

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice){

      $payment_invoice += $invoice->total_pay;
      $payment_receipt += $invoice->receipts->sum('amount_paid');

    }

     $total = $payment_invoice + $payment_receipt;
     $invoices_receipts_agent[] = ['name' => $agent->name, 'total' => $total];
  }
```

Note: I have used **sum** collection function to get sum of values of column **amount_paid** of a particular receipt. You could do same to get sum of total_pay column of an invoice like:

```
$total_paid = $agent->invoices()->sum('total_pay');
```

Comment: Why do you think this method will solve my issue? I will try ..but I want your opinion to know why you think this will solve the problem! Many thanks

Comment: In my comment I am trying to help you to organize better the code, and then look for any mistake after that.

Comment: So I guess you have a data issue. Did you check data using SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm it this current version of your code?

I see some typos like in:

```
$recepits = Recepit::whereInvoice_id($invoice->id_invoice)->get();
  if (count($receipts) > 0) {
```

Here we have issues:

1. Variable is named $recepits, but then called in next line with other name ($receipts).
2. $receipts should be a collection (result of Eloquent query) not an array. So to get count you have to say: $receipts->count()

If this is your final code, those are definitly error which are affecting your result.

Comment: Thank you for response..I've edited..in code was write well. And i've tried to change count($receipts) with $receipts->count()..but the numbers are the same..:(

Comment: Can you edit your code with actual version in order to give a more precise response? Thanks